# Ng-Zorro You Have Arrived

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I added the NG-Zorro library to my project and now every page that I open within my App just has the NG-Zorro logo and the text "You have Arrived".

Just wondering how to get rid of the logo/text so that I can see my pages ?

I've looked through the documentation [here](http://ng.ant.design/docs/getting-started/en), and the getting started shows that that's what's meant to happen. But it doesn't state how to get rid of the messaging.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the command `ng add ng-zorro-antd`, the CLI will invoke installations scripts that are implemented as schematics. In `ng-zorro-antd` the installation script replaces the content in `app.component.html` with code resulting in the image you're seeing. Simply revert those changes and you'll be back to where you were before adding the package!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually restore the changes from your Local History or Version Control. This was a problem with the first version(s) of ng-zorro

PS: The new versions of ng-zorro does not replace the main view if it is not the default.